# Why do I get Undefined error when trying to pass async API data as prop from parent to child component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Can someone tell me why I get `undefined` when trying to pass a prop down to child component?

Error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`

Sandbox reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-silence-3lgd9?file=/components/PostEditor.vue

Parent component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <PostEditor v-bind="post" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PostsEdit",
  data() {
    return {
      post: {},
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
    );
    this.post = await response.json();
  },
};
</script>
```

Child component:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    {{ title }}
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  post: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {},
    required: false,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: this.post.title,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      this.$emit("save", {
        ...this.formValues,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `v-bind="post"`

The child prop is named "post", but the parent is trying to bind several properties with `v-bind="post"`.

The binding name should match the target prop in the child:

```html
<!-- <PostEditor v-bind="post" /> --> ❌ binds subproperties of post

<PostEditor v-bind:post="post" />     ✅ binds post
<PostEditor :post="post" />           ✅ binds post (shorthand)
```

### `post` default prop value

The child's `post` prop has a `default` option of `() => {}`, but that arrow function returns nothing (`undefined`), as the curly brackets start a *block scope*. This is effectively the same as not having the `default` option.

You likely meant for `default` to return an *empty object*, which requires wrapping the curly braces in parentheses:

```js
// default: () => {}   // ❌ returns undefined
default: () => ({})    // ✅ returns {}
```

### `data()` not reactive

Even with the prop default fixed above, the `formValues.title` property in `data()` is initialized to `this.post.title`, which would be `undefined` because `post` is initially an empty object. The `post` value passed in from the parent is updated asynchronously, so the value is still the initial value from the parent (also an empty object) in `data()`.

Note that `data()` is not reactive, so it's only called once at initialization. Changes to `this.post` will *not* automatically update the data property.

### Solution: Render child after `post` populated

One solution is to defer rendering the child component until the `post` prop is populated in the parent so that the `post` prop would have the expected values for the child's `data()` initialization.

In the parent, initialize `post` to `null`, and use `v-if="post"` to conditionally render the child:

```html
<template>
  <div>                             
    <PostEditor :post="post" v-if="post" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      post: null,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-init-data-from-props?file=pages/index.vue)

Answer (score 1):

In the child component, you need to define the `props` section first and then access it through `computed`

```js
export default {
 props: { // change added
   post: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {},
    required: false,
   }
  }, // change added
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.post ? this.post.title : '',
    }
  },
```